# Can't enable my Module, Unknown Module error

Tags: magento2, module

my site is up so now I wan't to get into the back end to make some custom imports of products trough mysql.

Now I'm following the PHP Road-map, and wanted to make a testmodule, the problem is I stumble upon an error I can't seem to fix.

Here's the folder structure

[image]

Here's my composer located at the root of the module

[image]

Here's my registration located at the root of the module

[image]

Here's my module located at root/etc

[image]

And here' the error

[image]

Cache Management is disabled.

Comment: @ TanguyB Run the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be `php bin/magento module:enable Tanguy_TestModule --clear-static-content` if your module is set up correctly.

Yes the static content parameter is optional and is needed only if your module has static content. Anyway you can re-generate your static content with `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: is it possible to do it without clearing static content, I was lucky to have a back up of my css files, it deleted them all haha.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to enable a module is :

```
magento module:enable [-c|--clear-static-content] [-f|--force] [--all] Namespace_Module
```

For more detailed information, see this :
[official docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-enable.html)